# How can I transform an exclusive constraint relationship from ER to RM model?

Tags: database-design, relational-theory, relations, entity

Let say we have two entities `TEACHER` and `COURSE`. There are two relationships between them. A `TEACHER` can teaches a `COURSE`, and also can learn a `COURSE`, however, the `TEACHER` cannot teach and learn a `COURSE` at the same time.

Is it possible to ilustrate this constraint in the relational model? How?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

#### Short Answer

No.  This can only be enforced through transactional logic.  If you want to note it on the ER diagram, you can show some brief text below the necessary entity describing the constraint.  E.g. `Check student is not teacher`.  You can do this with other constraints with cardinalities or constraints that cannot be described solely through the diagram.

#### Long answer

I'm going to borrow this example from [PerformanceDBA's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/484814/performancedba) [IDEF1X Introduction](https://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Documentary%20Examples/IDEF1X%20Notation.pdf) to illustrate:

[image]

The relationship between `Teacher` and `CourseOffering` enforces that a `Course` has 1 `Teacher`.

If you tried to define something like a `CourseRole` so a `Person` could only have one `Role` within a class (so you couldn't have someone both as a student and a teacher), you'd have to check that:

1. There's only one `Person` assigned to a `Teacher` role
2. That `Person` was also a `Teacher`
3. That when the `CourseOffering` was created, one row must be inserted into the `CourseRole` for the `Teacher`,  otherwise you have a `CourseOffering` without a `Teacher`.

Which is way more work than checking:

```
IF StudentId = 
  (
    SELECT
      TeacherId
    FROM 
      CourseOffering 
    WHERE 
      CourseCode = @CourseCode
        AND Year = @Year 
        AND Semester = @Semester
  )
  THEN error out/rollback/etc.
```

Granted, there are situations in the real world where the relationship between a `Course` and a `Teacher` is M:M, there are 0:M TAs/student graders/etc. that would require a different model and different constraints.